# How to retrieve the current response body length?

Tags: asp.net-core

I need  to retrieve the response body length.

When I look at https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/wiki/Rolling-Notes-Response-Stream-Contract it is said that:

> Stream.Position {get} and Stream.Length {get} return cumulative bytes written

This is exactly what I need, but `httpContext.Response.Body.Length` raises the `NotSupportedException` and says "The stream is not seekable."

Should I use a delegating stream for counting bytes on each write?

Comment: Curious, what is the scenario where you need this for? Probably one way to get this info is to register for the `OnSendingHeaders` callback on the current response. Example: `httpContext.Response.OnSendingHeaders(callback: (state) => { var length: (HttpContext)state.ContentLength; }, state: httpContext)` .

Comment: I think I missed your last line of the post...sure, even that would work...you could write a middleware which is registered very early in the pipeline and  wraps the response body with a delegating stream...

Comment: @KiranChalla I require the content length for counting the consumed bandwidth. When the quota is exceeded, futher requests will be blocked/slowed down.
The `OnSendingHeaders` callback does not work: `ContentLength` property is set to `null`. This is the same with the `OnResponseCompleted` callback.

Comment: True, content-length can be null in some scenarios(where the content is not buffered)...BTW, what kind of host are you using?...i have come across this kind of scenario earlier too...could please post an issue to `https://github.com/aspnet/home` with detailed explanation as to what your scenario is...my goal is to see if we can provide a nice way to achieve this scenario especially if its something that people commonly do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for tracking the content length during stream writing.
The `ContentLengthTracker` class is designed for sharing the content length value between other classes.
The code is published at https://github.com/ycrumeyrolle/Throttling/blob/master/src/Throttling/Internal/ContentLengthTrackingStream.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ContentLengthTracker
{
    public long ContentLength { get; set; }
}

public class ContentLengthTrackingStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _inner;
    private readonly ContentLengthTracker _tracker;

    public ContentLengthTrackingStream(Stream inner, ContentLengthTracker tracker)
    {
        if (inner == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inner));
        }

        if (tracker == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tracker));
        }

        _inner = inner;
        _tracker = tracker;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
        => _inner.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek
        => _inner.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite
        => _inner.CanWrite;

    public override long Length
        => _inner.Length;

    public override long Position
    {
        get => _inner.Position;
        set => _inner.Position = value;
    }

    public override bool CanTimeout
        => _inner.CanTimeout;

    public override int ReadTimeout
    {
        get => _inner.ReadTimeout;
        set => _inner.ReadTimeout = value;
    }

    public override int WriteTimeout
    {
        get => _inner.WriteTimeout;
        set => _inner.WriteTimeout = value;
    }

    public ContentLengthTracker Tracker
        => _tracker;

    public override void Flush()
        => _inner.Flush();

    public override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => _inner.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        => _inner.Read(buffer, offset, count);

    public async override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await _inner.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        => _inner.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        Task<int> task = asyncResult as Task<int>;
        if (task != null)
        {
            return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        return _inner.EndRead(asyncResult);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        => _inner.Seek(offset, origin);

    public override void SetLength(long value)
       => _inner.SetLength(value);

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _tracker.ContentLength += count - offset;
        _inner.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        // _tracker.ContentLength += count - offset; // This is incorrect
        _tracker.ContentLength += count;
        return _inner.BeginWrite(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
    }

    public override void EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        => _inner.EndWrite(asyncResult);

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // _tracker.ContentLength += count - offset; // This is incorrect
        _tracker.ContentLength += count;
        return _inner.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        _tracker.ContentLength++;
        _inner.WriteByte(value);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _inner.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. It should not be subtracting offset. The count is the number of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are trying to get the ContentLength from within a middleware?

Here is an example Middleware.  It should be added to to the pipeline (startup.cs) before any response generating middleware such as useMVC or  useStaticFiles.

```
public class ContentLengthMiddleware
{
    RequestDelegate _next;

    public ContentLengthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            var response = context.Response;

            var bodyStream = response.Body;
            response.Body = buffer;

            await _next(context);
            Debug.WriteLine($"{request.Path} ({response.ContentType}) Content-Length: {response.ContentLength ?? buffer.Length}");
            buffer.Position = 0;
            await buffer.CopyToAsync(bodyStream);
        }
    }
}
```

For reasons that are beyond my understanding when returning static files (png, js, etc) the response body will be empty however ContentLength is set that is why I used the `response.ContentLength ?? buffer.Length`.

(Note to mod: sorry about the duplicate answer to two questions.  The other answer was incorrectly posted, too many tabs open.  I deleted it and reposted the answer here).

Comment: The drawback of this solution is the use of a `MemoryStream`.
It consumes uselessly memory.

Comment: I have overrided a `Stream` and just count at each write like this :
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _tracker.ContentLength += count - offset;
         _inner.Write(buffer, offset, count);
     }

Comment: @ycrumeyrolle could you explain a bit more exactly what you're doing or perhaps even post it as its own solution? I'm a bit of a novice in c#. My goal is to read the length of the rquest body without incurring a penalty if possible