# Setting Content-Length header in ASP.NET 5 response

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**TL; DR** I have an ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) application and just trying to set a HTTP Content-Length header in order to avoid chunked response.

To my surprise, it happens that this is a quite tricky task to accomplish in ASP.NET 5. Everything is running on Kestrel which from ASP.NET 5 Beta7 [supports writing chunked responses automatically when no content length is specified for the response](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7.aspx).

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652138/how-to-retrieve-the-current-response-body-length/31074575), but the difference is that the OP just wants to count a response size, while I need to ensure that the Content-Length header is sent within a response. Tried with many things so far, and the only thing that works is writing a custom Middleware:

```
public class WebApiMiddleware {
    RequestDelegate _next;

    public WebApiMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
         using (var buffer = new MemoryStream()) {
            var response = context.Response;

            var bodyStream = response.Body;
            response.Body = buffer;

            await _next(context);

            response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", new[] { buffer.Length.ToString()});
            buffer.Position = 0;
            await buffer.CopyToAsync(bodyStream);
        }
     }
}
```

However, this is highly inefficient since we are using additional memory while processing every request. Using a custom stream that just wraps around the `context.Response.Body` stream and additionally counts bytes doesn't work since the Microsoft team states that [once the amount of data they're willing to buffer has been written, it goes out on the wire and they don't store it any more](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/487#issuecomment-97695667), so I can, at best, add Content-Length to the last chunk which is not the wished behavior - I want to avoid chunking completely.

Any help is highly appreciated!

*p.s. I am aware that chunking is a regular feature of HTTP/1.1, but in my scenario it degrades performance so I want to avoid it without forcing the clients to send HTTP/1.0 requests.*

Comment: Do you know the length of the content without buffering it? Because if not this is unsolvable.

Comment: @usr I can calculate the length of the content at the end of each method. However, my controller has numerous methods, and I would like to avoid calling `toString()` on the response of each of them and then setting `Response.Headers.Append("Content-Length", retVal.Length.ToString());`. Some of these methods return `IEnumerable` (i.e. some collections), other return `IActionResult` etc. MVC somewhere in the pipeline already performs serialization of the response before it returns it, and I would like to grab that serialized response and set Content-Length header, if possible.

Comment: Once i added a incorrect content length in the request header and request got stalled(seemed like lost) in the custom middleware and never reached controller. Later removed the header , it worked fine.  It might be irrelevant to the question but commenting it as it might help somebody.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send header before sending response so you need to store whole response before sending it to determine length.

As you said `context.Response.Body` stream doesn't store to much before sending so overhead is not that big.

There is middleware that does similar thing: https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering/ResponseBufferingMiddleware.cs it is very similar to what you wrote but supports additional features like `IHttpBufferingFeature` to allows other middleware control buffering.

Checking for `bufferStream.CanSeek` is there to make sure nobody already wrapped response stream into buffering stream and avoid double buffering.

For your second question: this place is middlware.

Comment: Thank you for the response Pavel. Two questions:
1) How exactly is the solution with a middleware that you are proposing different from the one mentioned in the question with `MemoryStream`? I can see that you are checking `bufferStream.CanSeek`, does it mean that buffering can be turned off while writing the response?
2) Is there a place in MVC pipeline where I can read the content that is going to be sent and add appropriate header / do compression / whatever? That's actually the core of my original question, and frankly I cannot believe that such simple thing is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, you got an upvote from me. My second question should be "Is there a place in MVC pipeline where I can read the content *without buffering it*". If that is not possible, please give me some reference that supports it, otherwise I will wait to see if there is someone with better answer (even though it is hard to expect that someone gives better answer than the member of ASP.NET team :))

Comment: You can wrap the response stream and read there, but if you need to read everything before sending to client the only way is buffering.