# Adding Content-Length header in ASP.NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net 6 application. I would like to add the content-length header to the response for one of my endpoints. I found one way that [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998436/setting-content-length-header-in-asp-net-5-response) from another question on StackOverflow, but as mentioned the solution is not very efficient. Is there a way to add the content-length to the response? And it would be even better if the solution does not use a middleware and could be solved in the controller directly.

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CourseQueryDTO>>> GetCoursesInSemester     (string semesterId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<CourseQueryDTO> courses = await _courseService.GetCoursesInSemesterAsync(semesterId, cancellationToken);
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentLength, JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(courses).Length.ToString());
        return Ok(courses);
    }
```

The above code throws the following error: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13] Connection id "0HMNUQVREHBBL", Request id "0HMNUQVREHBBL:00000007": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (2210144 of 2221925).`

And on the frontend client I get this error: `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200`

However, the response status code is still 200.

Program.cs (pipeline order could make a difference)

```
...
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**UPDATE**:
What I did is that I added a custom header that contains the size of the response body in bytes

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CourseQueryDTO>>> GetCoursesInSemester     (string semesterId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<CourseQueryDTO> courses = await _courseService.GetCoursesInSemesterAsync(semesterId, cancellationToken);
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Size", JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(courses).Length.ToString());
        return Ok(courses);
    }
```

This seems to work, as long as I whitelist the header for CORS.
Is this solution bad?

Comment: Are you looking for `Response.Headers.Add()` ? If you look for more info about headers => https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-add-custom-headers/

Comment: I did try that, but it was causing errors.

Comment: What were the errors ?

Comment: Why do you want this? It matters. The `Content-Length` header isn't required and isn't included when servers send a stream of data, simply because there's no way to know the full size of the response until the entire stream is consumed. High-performance ones  won't send it when they serialize API responses either, because calculating it requires serializing the entire response in memory first before sending it to the client. That's far too expensive for an optional header. ASP.NET Core serializes data directly to the network stream, it doesn't cache it first.

Comment: Ok, but I don't get it why you want to set the `content-length` in the first place...

Comment: The reason is that I want to add a progress loader in the frontend application, and I would like to know the total size of the body to calculate how much data has been downloaded.

Comment: That's not a good reason. You're asking the server to severely reduce its scalability, or worse, require extra servers, just to display a progress bar.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right. Do you have any ideas on how I can do something similar?

Comment: Many sites display an infinite progress bar or a spinner. Besides, `GetCoursesInSemesterAsync` may take *more* time than transferring the serialized data over the network. How important is it to display an accurate progress bar? You may be able to send notifications to the client through eg SignalR. Such progress notifications could include messages, not just item counts, eg `retrieving items`, `sending items` etc. SignalR allows [sending responses as a stream too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Another possibility is to add a custom header with the item count. This would allow the client to calculate the approximate size and use a bytes received event to track the transfer progress

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did something similar to what you suggested. I updated my question. I would appreciate your thoughts on it.